# How to access the HTTP method within a Ballerina request interceptor

Tags: http, ballerina, http-method

I'm working with Ballerina and I've implemented a request interceptor for my HTTP service. In this interceptor, I need to access the HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, etc.) used in the incoming request.
I've been going through the documentation and example provided at https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/http-request-interceptors/

Is it possible to track the HTTP method within a request interceptor in Ballerina, and if so, how can this be achieved? Or is it limited to tracking the path only in the Request Interceptor?

Answer (score 2):

We can access the HTTP method within a Ballerina Request Interceptor using the `method` field in the [http:Request](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/http/2.4.0#Request) object.

```php
resource function 'default [string... path](http:RequestContext ctx, http:Request req) returns http:NextService|error? {
    string method = req.method;
    // ...
}
```